# C# Unity while key pressed if condition true or false

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, object, game-development

So I'm new to C# I somewhat know Python I couldn't understand how functions work I tried doing something like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class collisiondetectorleft : MonoBehaviour
{
    public class Triggerdetecting()
    {
        public void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
        {
            if (other.attachedRigidbody)
                other.attachedRigidbody.AddForce((Vector3.up * 10);
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            //I'm so lost
            Triggerdetecting objTriggerdetecting = new Triggerdetecting();
        }
    }

}
```

I'm trying to create some sort of hitbox by detecting trigger if a button pressed and meets the condition make the object more faster. I tried few ways to call function non of them worked. Thank you for your time. If you unable to understand what I meant you can ask me I'll try to explain in other ways.

Want something like this:

```
def detection():
    if OnTriggerStay == True:
        moveobject up

if Input.GetKeyDown("space")) == True:
    detection()
```

Comment: What do you mean faster? I can write the code but give me more specifics

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class collisiondetectorleft : MonoBehaviour
{
    //create bool to set it true or false while inside the object
    private bool _canHit;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (_canHit)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
            {
                _canHit = false;
                //task
            }
        }  
    }
    //set _canHit true if object enters trigger
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.attachedRigidbody)
            _canHit = true;
    }
    //set _canHit false if object exits trigger
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.attachedRigidbody)
            _canHit = false;
    }
}
```

I was able to detect and log while true but I didn't figured how to react to object that triggers

Comment: If OnTriggerEnter and OnTriggerExit are event handlers, then you can do: ObjectTriggering.SomethingHappended += collisiondetectorleft.OnTriggerEnter;

Comment: @Amit `OnTriggerEnter` and `OnTriggerExit` are **methods** -> no

Answer (score 0):

I would go the same route as you did in your answer attempt.

The last bit missing in order to b able to actually use the according object is simple: Instead of a `bool` rather directly store the object

```
public class collisiondetectorleft : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Collider _currenTarget;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (_currenTarget && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            Debug.Log($"I am interacting with {_currentTarget}");

            _currenTarget = null;
        }  
    }
    
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (!other.attachedRigidbody) return;

        _currenTarget = other;
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other != _currenTarget) return;

        _currenTarget = null;
    }
}
```